# putting d3.js elements on the slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Please first take a look on this picture : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By25CEM_KEOiYzdYaWVicnp6Zm8/edit?usp=sharing

Now i want to make something like that but i want to put d3.js elements on a slider like that instead of images like a rectange, circle, square, triangle so that user can move them with arrow buttons shown in the image.

I just wanted to know if it is possible with d3.js and if Yes, please tell me how or from where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make something like that using D3.

One way you could do it is to draw the tiles as rectangles using SVG and then have a clip path that hides the tiles that are outside of the frame of what you want to see. The left and right arrows would update the xScale domain which would slide the tiles left and right. And, you can register click events on the rect elements to create links on the tiles.

See this for some ideas on how to start: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

If you aren't already somewhat familiar with d3, you should probably start with a basic tutorial like: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html before you dive into the deep end.